# Mobile application connect to server with "vodafone" sim,but not connect with "Idea" sim.

Tags: java-me, gprs, midp-2.0, cldc, nokia-s40

I'm creating a mobile app with j2me. My configuration is **CLDC-1.1, MIDP-2.0.**

I'm sending the request to server via (https and http)  and get response from my application through GPRS.

If I'm using **vodafone** sim then it will works fine. But if I'm using **idea** sim then the request cannot send to server from my mobile application "**The Http operation**" exception is thrown.

But if I type `the url in the mobile phone browser` the page correctly displayed (when I'm using idea sim and vodafone sim). And when I use `the url google.com` (http://www.google.com) in my mobile app ,when im using `idea gprs sim or vodafone gprs sim its work fine`.

But when I use the `url of my server application` (my office server app url) in my mobile app ,when I'm using `idea gprs sim sim its not work fine`, the follwoing exception thrown "**java.io.IOException : 60 - Error in HTTP Operation**".If i type the url in the mobile phone browser then its correctly working.

I'm using **"nokia c2-01"** for testing mobile.It is a **"s40"** device. So please give the ideas. All are welcome to provide your ideas.

Comment: I CAN CONNECT TO OTHER SITES "http://www.google.com","https://www.onlinesbi.com/" via my mobile application.But i cannot connect to my server .So please help me "funkybro" and others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.Some ISP such as Airtel,Vodafone,etc.Sometimes block the network if the try to connect via application.Because of preventing from malicious attack,prevent the network traffic,etc.

The problem is dependent with respect to Isp (Internet service provider) .Now its working to me.

Answer (score 2):

It must be down to the access point which on some Nokias is separately configurable for the browser and Java apps.

Can any other Java app access the network?  If not then it's definitely the access point; you need to dive around in your configuration settings.